# CSS truncation with flexbox: IE 10/11

Tags: css, flexbox, internet-explorer-11, internet-explorer-10

I'm trying to set up a layout where the text in the left-hand column will become truncated if/when it runs out of space, but the text in the right-hand column will always display in full. This codepen shows exactly what should happen -

http://codepen.io/robinkparker/pen/oLQZqv

```
<div class="tile">
  <a class="action" href="#">
    <div class="subtitle">
      Some text that I just -know- will be too long, and should be truncated using CSS for responsiveness.
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      Some text that I just -know- will be too long, and should be truncated using CSS for responsiveness.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="action action--r" href="#">
    <div class="sibling">&lt;sibling&gt;</div>
  </a>
</div>

.tile {
  border: 1px solid black
  display: flex
  margin: 1em 0
}

.action {
  border: 1px dashed black
  color: black
  flex-shrink: 1
  flex-grow: 1
  min-width: 0
  max-width: 100%
  padding: 1em
  text-decoration: none
}

.action--r {
  flex-grow: 0
  flex-shrink: 0
}

.subtitle {
  display: inline-block
  width: 100%

  white-space: nowrap
  overflow: hidden
  text-overflow: ellipsis
}
```

This works perfectly in most of the modern browsers I need to support, but I can't work out how to get this working in IE10 and IE11, since I have very limited experience working with flexbox. Can anyone help?!

Thanks,
Robin

Comment: Start by researching what vendor prefixes and/or alternative properties flexbox needs in older IE; https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn265027(v=vs.85).aspx has a comprehensive list.

Comment: You could also use either CanIUse.com to check compatibility or some sort of autoprefixer to run the check and update your code for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As recommended by @GregMcMullen, [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/) is a great tool. There's a few things you were missing, though, to make this work for IE (tested on IE10 and 11):

1. `.action` needs `display: block` and `overflow: hidden`
2. All flexbox properties should be prefixed with `-ms`. `-ms-flexbox` is for IE10, while `-ms-flex` is for IE11.
3. `.subtitle` didn't need the extra rules you had

```css
.tile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -ms-flex;
  display: flex;
}

.action {
  display: block;
  border: 1px dashed black;
  color: black;
  -ms-flex: 1 1 auto;
  flex: 1 1 auto;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.action--r {
  -ms-flex: 0 0 auto;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}

.subtitle {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <a class="action" href="#">
    <div class="subtitle">
      Some text that I just -know- will be too long, and should be truncated using CSS for responsiveness.
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      Some text that I just -know- will be too long, and should be truncated using CSS for responsiveness.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="action action--r" href="#">
    <div class="sibling">&lt;sibling&gt;</div>
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

simply add `overflow: hidden` property to `.action` class (tested on IE11)

```css
.tile {
  border: 1px solid black;
  display: flex;
  margin: 1em 0;
}
.action {
  border: 1px dashed red;
  color: black;
  flex-shrink: 1;
  flex-grow: 1;
  min-width: 0;
  max-width: 100%;
  padding: 1em;
  text-decoration: none;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.action--r {
  flex-grow: 0;
  flex-shrink: 0;
}
.subtitle {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="tile">
  <a class="action" href="#">
    <div class="subtitle">
      Some text that I just -know- will be too long, and should be truncated using CSS for responsiveness.
    </div>
    <div class="subtitle">
      Some text that I just -know- will be too long, and should be truncated using CSS for responsiveness.
    </div>
  </a>
  <a class="action action--r" href="#">
    <div class="sibling">&lt;sibling&gt;</div>
  </a>
</div>
```